# Trying to compare items in an array to see if they are the same

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm creating a function with a for loop and if statement to check if every item stored in a given array are exactly the same i.e. 1,1,1,1 or "a","a","a","a" 
If they are I want "true" returned and if not "false"

```
function isSame(arr) {
var compare = i
for(i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++){
if(arr[0] == compare)
console.log(true)
else {
    return false;
}}
}
```

currently I get false returned no matter what I put in.

Comment: You can use this: `function isSame(arr) { return arr.every( x => x === arr[0] ); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change compare = arr[0] variable to store first item and for loop to compare with remain item.

```
var arr = [1,1,1,1];
function isSame(arr) {
var compare = arr[0]
var result = true;
for(i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++){
if(arr[i] == compare){
console.log(true)
}
else {
    return false;
}}

return result;
}

console.log(isSame(arr));
```

```js
var arr = [1,1,1,1];
function isSame(arr) {
var compare = arr[0]
var result = true;
for(i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++){
if(arr[i] == compare){
console.log(true)
}
else {
    return false;
}}

return result;
}

console.log('is same? ' + isSame(arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Set` to get unique values. If there is only one unique, means the array elements are the same.

```js
let checkIfSame = (a) => new Set(a).size === 1;

console.log( checkIfSame( [1, 1, 1, 1] ) );
console.log( checkIfSame( [1, 1, 3, 1] ) );
```

Comment: This is pretty neat. Though, I'd be curious about efficiency. Would `new Set` have to evaluate the entirety of an array, whereas something like `.every()` would exit early? Perhaps the callback of an Array function like `every` would immediately render it less efficient, though I'm not sure of `Set` performance. Just curious. +1 though - this was clever as heck.

Comment: Another side note about this, is that will return `false` for an empty array. If the expected value is `true` for that case, then a sort of check may be needed.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is not yet defined when you do `var compare = i`, so `compare` is initialized as `undefined`. You then never update `compare` again. Therefore your current code is just doing `if (arr[0] == undefined)` for every item.

An alternative would be to use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which returns a boolean indicating whether or not every item in the array satisfies the given predicate.

```js
const isSame = (arr) => arr.every(i => i === arr[0]);

console.log( isSame(['1','1','1']) );
console.log( isSame(['a','b','c']) );
```

Answer (score 0):

you are never returning true. However, if you did, your algorithm is not correct. For example, as others said, you are declaring your i to some value that is not defined. Here's a sample that works for your purpose. The only limitation that you may want to consider is if the argument is in fact an array

```
function isSame(arr){  
if (arr.length === 0)
    return true
let toReturn = true
const firstElement = arr[0]

for (let element of arr){
    if (element !== firstElement){
        toReturn = false
        break
    }
}
return toReturn
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize `compare` with `i`, at that point `i` is not defined at all. Right now you are trying to compare every element of array to `undefined`. That's why you get false. You should change your code to something like this:

```
function isSame(arr) {
  var compare = arr[0];
  var allSame = true;
  for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(!allSame) return allSame;
    allSame = arr[i] === compare;
  }
  return allSame;
}
```

In ES6 syntax it can also be simplified to:

```
function isSame(arr) {
 return arr.every(item => item === arr[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have noted, the first line `var compare = i` of the function `isSame()` will store the `undefined` value on the variable `compare`, whit this setup your loop is always comparing the **first element** of the `array` with the `undefined` value on each iteration.

It would be much better if you compare the first element of the array with the other elements. Something like this:

```js
function isSame(arr)
{
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] !== arr[0])            
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

console.log(isSame([1,1,1]));
console.log(isSame([1,2,1]));
console.log(isSame([]));
console.log(isSame([1]));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

As a side note, you should note that this will only work nicely if the array holds [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Data_types). To see why this, check next example:

```js
console.log({key:"value"} === {key:"value"});
console.log([1,2] === [1,2]);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getUniqueValues = arr => arr.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) == i)
const isSame = arr => arr.length > 1 && getUniqueValues(arr).length === 1 ? true:false

console.log(isSame([1])) //false
console.log(isSame([1,2,3,4,4])) //false
console.log(isSame(['a','a','b'])) //false
console.log(isSame([1,1,1,1,1])) //true
console.log(isSame(['a','a','a','a'])) //true
```